# Different outputs from custom JsonConverter via options?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, jsonserializer

**Question as short as possible:**
I have written a custom JsonConverter to serialize/deserialize data back and forth and want to be able to control the output via flags/options I pass to the converter.

**The full story**
asp.net Core 5 backend running in conjunction with a vue-frontend. Connected via SignalR. The system controls devices (status to the front-end, commands/settings to the backend). The backend holds a list of devices and whenever a change occurs it serializes this device (via my converter) and sends the data to the front-end.
From time to time I want to store the settings in a JsonFile on the disk to retain settings that were made in the front-end. Works with no problems by serializing my list of devices.

Now, some devices have volatile data, that I do want to be displayed in the front-end but when dumping this device to the disk, I don't want them permanently stored as they have no meaning for the next time the settings are read back in.

**I tried...**
`[JsonIgnore]` of course is no option, as this would ignore the parameter when serializing for the front-end as well.

I thought a `[CustomAttribute]` could help me, but when serializing I of course can check if that property has my custom attribute, but at that moment I do not know if I am serializing for front-end or settings-file.

I also tried to extend the `JsonSerializerOptions` to maybe attach a parameter of my own, but that class is sealed - so now way there.

Yes I could copy my entire JsonConverter, give it another name and when serializing for front-end use Converter-A and when writing settings to the disk use Converter-B, but come on... That can't be it!

It feels my whole approach is wrong?

Comment: Hi @sutt, It seems you want to optional serialize the model data. What is your scenario? I mean when you want to serialize or not?

Comment: @Rena, thanks for taking the time to answer. As mentioned in the original post I wanted to sometimes remove certain properties when serializing. Serializing in general will always take place, but having different "targets" I am serializing for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, kind of embarrassing, but I think I have a solution.

I simply add a property to the JsonConverter that I will set when creating the converter for the settings-file-conversion.
When instantiating the InnerConverter I pass along that parameter to the constructor and store it there in a private variable.

In combination with a custom attribute, I'm pretty much where I want to be without the need to duplicate my converter.